# How to select first element anywhere in the document

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BooksInfo>
    <Publisher>
        <PublisherName>Publisher One</PublisherName>
    </Publisher>

    <Publisher>
        <PublisherName>Publisher Two</PublisherName>
    </Publisher>
</BooksInfo>
```

If I use this: `//PublisherName[1]` then I get both the `PublisherName` elements in the result. I want only the first one.

Comment: BTW, this is because each `<PublisherName>` is at `position()=1` in its context (first child of `<Publisher>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search the entire document and then apply the index, you have to put the search expression in round brackets:

```
(//PublisherName)[1]
```

Comment: Can you please tell how can I select the text also from first node. If I use `(//PublisherName)[1]/text()` it shows invalid result.

Answer (score 2):

Just use brackets around the element name:

```
(//PublisherName)[1]
```